# Vector Parametrization of intersection of a plane and an elliptical cylinder

Tags: calculus

Plane: $x+y+z= 1$

Elliptical cylinder: $(y/3)^2 + (z/8)^2 =1$

Find the parametrization in which they intersect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: A point $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3$ is on the zylinder, iff for one $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$ $y = 3\cos\theta$, $z = 8\sin\theta$. Now use the equation of the plane to derive the associated value of $x$.

Comment: Thanks! But the domain of this problem is all real numbers so it is not possible to use y=3cos(theta) and z=8sin(theta)

Comment: Is there a possible way to do parametrization in terms of t? As in r(t)=<xt,yt,zt>?

Comment: As in $r(t) = \langle 1 - 3 \cos(t) - 8\sin(t), 3\cos(t), 8\sin(t)\rangle$?

Comment: That makes sense. How did you figure out what y and z were equal to?